# ulimit not working properly

Tags: memory, ulimit

i am trying to limit the memory usage of a process using ulimit

```
ulimit -Sv 100000
ulimit -St 10
fakechroot ./compiledfile
```

i am running the command in the same terminal (i am using ubuntu 16.04) and the source code of compiled file is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        malloc(110000000);
        pf("allocated : %d\n",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the process should get terminated because of memory limit..but it is running till the timelimit end.I don't  understand why.
I am novice,pardon me if the question is silly..any help or suggestion is appreciated..thanks

Comment: Not sure, but does `fakechroot` create a new process? `ulimit` only affects the current process. You could try running a script with `ulimit` and your `./compiledfile` inside `fakechroot`

Comment: @joe P i have tried without fakechroot (  ./compiledfile ) bt no change

Comment: You should check the return value of `malloc`. It will return `NULL` when allocation fails due to memory limit or other reason.